# Access password protected network folder with python

Tags: python

I am on Python Version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

The OS is Windows 7 64.

Is there a way to access a password protected network folder like `r'\\server_name\password_protected_folder'` for, say, writing a text file, by passing the password as a string to an appropriate function?

PS. I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967752/how-to-access-password-protected-shared-folder-through-python) link but no answer has been given.

Comment: As in the other link, what is the protocol you're using?

Comment: I am not familiar with these concepts. If what you are asking is what appears in the Local Area Connection Properties dialog of ```Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center```, then I see 
```Client for Microsoft Networks,
QoS Packet Scheduler,
File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks,
(TCP/IPv6),
(TCP/IPv4),
Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver,
Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder```. If what you are asking is sth else, kindly suggest where I can find this information.

Comment: These information are not really much useful. To code something that  makes two pc in communication you need to define a set of rules of request and reply. This set is normally indicated as a protocol. for instance FTP protocol could be suitable for what you want to do

Comment: ok, so what you ask, if I understand well, is not sth that is already defined in the LAN settings but sth that will be defined in the script itself right? If FTP could be suitable as an example then maybe it could help me or point me to a direction to search.

Comment: Yes, it is not something related to LAN. I suggest you to first try to write your code and then asks if you need help. A good way to start with FTP in python is [this](https://www.techinfected.net/2017/07/create-simple-ftp-server-client-in-python.html).